# Test-Driven Development with plain C: manage multiple modules

Tags: c, tdd

I am new to test-driven development, but I'm loving it. There is, however, a main problem that prevents me from using it effectively.

I work for embedded medical applications, plain C, with safety issues.

Suppose you have module `A` that has a function `A_function()` that I want to test. This function call a function `B_function`, implemented in module `B`.
I want to decouple the module so, as James Grenning teaches, I create a Mock module `B` that implements a mock version of `B_function`.

However the day comes when I have to implement module `B` with the real version of `B_function`. Of course the two `B_function` can not live in the same executable, so I don't know how to have a unique "launcher" to test both modules.

James Grenning way out is to replace, in module `A`, the call to `B_function` with a function pointer that can have the value of the mock or the real function according to the need. 
However I work in a team, and I can not justify this decision that would make no sense if it were not for the test, and no one asked me explicitly to use test-driven approach.

Maybe the only way out is to generate different a executable for each module.

Any smarter solution?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need a single executable to test both functions?

Comment: The test suite I use (CppUTest) supports many "test suites", but generates only one executable. My fear in having many executables is that I will not run all of them every time, and I will discover that one test is broken too late.Maybe I only need a more powerful IDE that supports multiple project active as one and runs more executables with one command.Which one do you use?

Comment: Running all of your tests every time should be a no-brainer.  Script it, make sure it works right and run that instead of running the test tool directly.

Comment: agree, I'll go that way.

Comment: I need a single executable to test as downloading to the embedded device takes a minimum of 3 minutes, which includes physically inserting and removing the programming dongle. (Our current test scripts utilize the GetATechnitianToDoIt() function)

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what you've described, I would suggest that's a horrible reason to use a function pointer.  It will jack up your ability to debug, analyze core dumps, and it will complicate future development / maintenance.  Function pointers have their place, but this isn't one of them.

I think you're approaching the testing from the wrong point of view.  A_func depends upon B_func's presence for it to operate.  Therefore, you can't truly test A without having the actual implementation of B in place.  Putting a mock B_func in place will only generate a limited set of tests for A_func.  By definition, you can't fully exercise A_func without the real B_func in place.

Presuming you're not dealing with a cascading series of module inclusions, the appropriate test suite would have some tests to exercise B_func and then some additional tests for exercising the variations that A_func can go through.  It's understood that you may have some redundancy between the tests for B_func and the indirect testing of B_func from A_func, but it's generally not a big deal.

Comment: I agree that's a bad use for function pointers, but I don't agree that I can't test a function without the implementation of the functions it depends on. In embedded SW, "B_func" might be a function that accesses the HW that maybe is not available, while "A_func" might simply be a business function that manages data, and can be tested with fake values.
By mocking B_func I don't limit the test on A_func but, on the contrary, I can let B_func return any value, even the ones the are hardly ever returned.

Comment: @Angelo - that is true so long as B_func has a contract in place as to what it is guaranteed to produce.  If the root issue is missing X (hardware) to drive B_func, **and** B_func is well specified on its returns, then you could use some pre-compiler conditional flags to stub in the test harness you need.  It makes the code a little uglier, but is far more tolerable to the rest of the team.

Comment: What if you give it a hip name like [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)? Is it a good idea then?

Comment: @Philip - only if you don't intend to try and debug core dumps.... :-)